# How to do REST api call on build event

Tags: c#, rest, post-build-event, pre-build-event, build-events

I am working on .net standard library.

I have two requirements

Note : client project means - c# project which consumes my library.

1. Call a REST api on pre or post build event of client project.
2. Based on the response , I should create a enum class dynamically on the client project.

Gone through build event docs from Microsoft , but couldn't find any specific to call rest api or dynamic code creation on build time.

Can someone help me achieve this.

Thanks.
Noorul

Comment: Why not just call and cache values on startup?

Comment: yes, thats what we do right now. For certain reasons like automating the build process , we have to do the above .

Comment: It's sounds like a job for a cd/ci, however if you need more control over prebuild, use powershell

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your reply , can we do rest api call and dynamic code generation using powershell !?  can you give some guidance !

Comment: For the first part, you can use CURL. See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html